# calcuale ----OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
en_1 = 1
n = 1
factorial = 1
invfactorial = 1
    while en_1 > 1e-6 :
        en = en_1 +invfactorial
        n = n + 1
        factorial = factorial * n
        invfactorial = float(1.0/factorial)
        en_1 = en 
print "e = %.5f"%en
```

I want to calculate e via this code, but it cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en_1 > 1e-6` will never evaluate to `True`.  `en_1` just gets bigger and bigger.  At some point you end up with numbers so large that Python can't handle the conversions.  Instead compare to `invfactorial > 1e-6`:

```
en_1 = 1
n = 1
factorial = 1
invfactorial = 1
while invfactorial > 1e-6:  # changed comparison
    en = en_1 +invfactorial
    n = n + 1
    factorial = factorial * n
    invfactorial = float(1.0/factorial)
    en_1 = en # don't need both en_1 and en
```

This could be made much simpler:

```
e = n = fac = 1
while 1.0/fac > 1e-6:
    fac *= n
    e += 1.0/fac
    n += 1
```

Comment: OK，I will try it later. Thanks a lot.